# Add product to guest cart with custom option and its price in Magento 2 api

Tags: magento2, cart, api, custom-options

I need to add product in cart  using magento 2 api.

I am using below api

```
"rest/V1/guest-carts/{cart_id}/items
```

I am passing parameters like below,

```
    {
    "cartItem": {
        "sku": "paneer_chilli-1",
        "qty": "1",
        "name": "Paneer Chilli",
        "price": 100,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "3a43e2fc1ed26db195a8ceee00929bcb",
        "product_option": {
            "extension_attributes": {
                "custom_options": [{
                    "option_id": 6,
                    "option_value": 2
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

dosent work, it is giving error like below,

```
Property "CustomOptions" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface".
```

What is option_id and option_value in my case when I have to pass custom option with multiple option with its price (checkbox)

It will be great if someone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/ > **quoteGuestCartItemRepositoryV**1

In your case, should change to underscore format

```
{
    "cartItem": {
        "quote_id": {cart id},
        "sku": {sku},
        "qty": 1,
        "product_option":{
            "extension_attributes":{
                "custom_options":[
                    {
                        "option_id":"1",
                        "option_value":"2"
                    }
                    ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for you reply, but now it is giving, "Please specify product's required option(s)." i am updating my latest json object in question, it will be great of you can suggest something.

Comment: The values and option id should match exactly. Please check the options present to the product by using SKU than you can place exact values which makes move forward from above error

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is running into the same issue and looking for a solution, to add a product with customized options selected through the guest-carts rest api in the original question the `custom_options` attribute was incorrect at least in one way.

Adding the product to the cart will only work when the key is set to the option's ID and the value to the option's value ID

Example

```
   "cartItem": {
        "sku": "paneer_chilli-1",
        "qty": "1",
        "name": "Paneer Chilli",
        "price": 100,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "3a43e2fc1ed26db195a8ceee00929bcb",
        "product_option": {
            "extension_attributes": {
                "custom_options": ["522465": 403826]
            }
        }
    }
```

To verify you are using the absolute correct ID's for example when you keep receiving the error `Property "CustomOptions" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface".` it's worth doublechecking through this query using product's ID which will output list of correct possbile combinations of custom options:

```
SELECT opt.option_id, val.option_type_id, val.sku
FROM catalog_product_option AS opt
         LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_type_value AS val ON val.option_id = opt.option_id
WHERE opt.product_id = 1234; # <<== YOUR_PRODUCT_ID

# OUTPUT:
# | option_id | option_type_id | sku          |
# | :---      | :---           | :---         |
# | 522465    | 403826         | mild-spicy   |
# | 522465    | 403827         | extra-spicy  |
# | 522465    | 403828         | black-pepper |
```